# Creation order of network<->service in docker stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

In docker-sompose:

```
services:
  srvA:
  (..)
  networks:
        - backend
  srvB:
  (..)
  networks:
        - frontend
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: overlay
  backend:
    driver: overlay
```

when I start `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml myname` the order of creating network-service pairs is random and if `srvA` starts before creation of `backend` network this gives an error:

> failed to create service srvA: Error response from
>   daemon: network myname_backend not found

**How to assure that networks get created before services?**